# Laravel artisan migration error on square brackets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I'm trying to generate my database via Laravel's migration files, but when I try to do so I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in D:\wamp24\www\laravel\app\controllers\SomeController.php
```

This is driving me crazy, I can run the migration files when I comment out the code in my controllers, but I can't keep on doing this.

I also don't want to rewrite all my code, since I use the square brackets almost everytime I declare an array (using the square brackets is a lot quicker than typing 'array( ~ )' ... )

I'm using **PHP 5.3.13** on a wampserver (2.4) with apache 2.2.22 on Win 8.1.

Laravel Framework version 4.0.10.

The code that gives the error is the following:

```
class SomeController extends BaseController {
    public function someFunc() {
        $var= Model::create([
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'description' => Input::get('description'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Anyone who knows a solution to this error?

Comment: can you post code to SomeController.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your `PHP` version doesn't support `[]` array syntax, try:

```
$var = Model::create(array(
    'title' => Input::get('title'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
));
```

It is not supported in `PHP < 5.4`. Upgrade your `PHP` version or use `array()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: strange, the code renders fine otherwise with the square brackets (I mean the controllers work fine once the database is migrated...)

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: I was using php 5.4 on my wamp server (this is why the controllers would work), but I was using php 5.3 on my windows system to migrate the database... Changed my Windows systems Environment Variables and now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with formatting.

Try:

```
class SomeController extends BaseController {
public function someFunc() {
    $var= Model::create(array(
        'title' => Input::get('title'),
        'description' => Input::get('description'),
    ));
  }
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

php 5.3.x not support short array , try to change it like this

```
Model::create(array(
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'description' => Input::get('description')
    ));
```